# How to access and view IBM Cloud support ticket

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation, ibm-appid

I am trying to raise a support ticket with IBM Cloud Support in regards to the Watson Assistant. I can create tickets with no issue, however, I am unable to view the support ticket from the console and therefore, can't communicate with the support team... When I click to view my support tickets, I am redirected to the regular dashboard.

How can I get in contact with support for IBM Cloud?

Comment: Are you clicking on "Support"->"View tickets"? It directs me to the ticket overview.

Comment: Yes but I’m redirected to the dashboard (above link)

Answer (score 1):

The process to get support and to view support tickets is described in the [IBM Cloud documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/get-support/howtogetsupport.html#getting-customer-support). The docs also have [information about how to contact the support team, e.g., to escalate a ticket](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/get-support/quicktickresp.html). That information includes a phone number and a link to a chat option.

Answer (score 0):

Watson Assistant is under Platform as a Service within IBM and a ticket can be generated from here as well.

Create PaaS ticket: https://console.bluemix.net/unifiedsupport/tickets/add